# Using ADAL with SharePoint Framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, adal

I've setup a web part with SharePoint framework that requires access to the Microsoft Graph for displaying the recently used files.

I've followed the instruction here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/call-microsoft-graph-from-your-web-part.md

I am not using the latest version of adal-angular because it was having timeout issues, it is also said in the guide above to use version 1.0.12 so I am using that version. For doing the component, I inspired myself from the Implicit Flow example: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-aad-implicitflow

My component works fine on the local workbench.

On the SharePoint workbench, I get the following error

> Token renewal operation failed due to timeout

When deployed, I ask for a Sign In, which opens a popup window but instead of coming back to the page I was, this popup stays open and that is where I see my recent files.

Am I doing anything wrong? I would like this to work as it does on the local workbench.

Comment: I asked this recently of other MVPs who are more familiar with SPFx than I am and they indicated it was currently not possible to use the ADAL framework with SPFx.

Comment: Just today I've submitted a PR fixing issue that sounds similar to what you're describing (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/pull/167). Would you mind checking if the latest code fixes the issue for you?

Comment: @WaldekMastykarz-MVP. I Just tried it and no luck. Here is a [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/e4ffe149f043f4926e79a26445bcdd89). The window to the right is the one that popped up. It has the id_token defined in the URL. Also, when I signin on the window to the left, there is a refresh happening.

Comment: Which browser are you using @FrancisFilion?

Comment: @WaldekMastykarz-MVP Chrome (Stable channel), both normal and private mode. Tested with Firefox and same behavior. Should I try on a non-dev SharePoint site? Could the behavior be different?

Comment: Could it be that your issue is related to Office UI Fabric React: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/150#issuecomment-290382591?

Comment: This made me do some more testing. So I do have this error on /_layouts/15/workbench.aspx and the error in the console happens twice. Once when the page load with no web part in it and each time I add the web part. There is no error on the "deployed" version when I add it on a Classic SharePoint page but I get the content in the popup as described before. I decided to test the "deployed" version to a new modern page and the behavior is similar to the /_layouts/15/workbench.aspx. The error, however, is a 400 on https://emapp.sharepoint.com/sites/emsb-dev-portal/SitePages/access_token=...

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue while working and got a work around which is "We can you please try changing Redirect URL to any Classic page".

The problem is while requesting the Access Token from Modern Page, it throws an error. So, I changed the Redirect URL to one of my Classic Page.

I hope, this might work for you as well.